# Water feed pipe diameter: is 1/2" OK?

Tags: pex, bypass

The 3/4" water feed in a slab has a leak.  A proposed bypass includes a  1/2 inch PEX, run through the ceiling.  Why should a 1/2 inch PEX be used to bypass and not a 3/4 inch?  Assume that the slab pipe and the PEX pipe are the same length.

Comment: Is the PEX being run inside the broken feed or separately?  What diameter pipes receive the existing 3/4 run?

Comment: Have you asked the person submitting the proposal? They would have way more facts than we have.

Comment: Reject the proposal and find a better plumber. 1/2" main feed will cause pressure issues, no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming when you say "water feed" that you mean your incoming water main from the water company or well.  If that's leaking then it needs to be replaced which I believe you already know.

I am also assuming that by proposing to "bypass" with 1/2" PEX they are somehow going to put another parallel pipe in place or try to force the 1/2" through the existing 3/4".

I'm not sure either of these plans are all that good and the main reason is that you'll now be stuck with a 1/2" water service to your property and that's likely going to be deficient.  The 1/4" difference sound slight but remember that the cross-sectional area of a pipe (i.e. the IMPORTANT part) varies with the square of the radius.  So the 1/2" pipe has an area of 50% of the 3/4".

This comes from simple calculations using the typical ID of 3/4 and 1/2 PEX as 0.681" and 0.485" respectively.  Using the formula of A = pi * r^2 you can calculate the two as having cross-sectional areas of 0.36 sq-in and 0.18 sq-in.  That's 50% less and that's a LOT!

Let me suggest an alternative.  It's quite possible for a horizontal drilling contractor to drill in a new line and hit a 12x12" hole in your slab.  Using that they can then pull in a new 3/4" (or even larger) pipe and you won't be left with an inadequate water main.  They will likely need to cut such an opening in your slab and also will likely need to excavate a hole to get access to the water main.

Many plumbers work with these contractors but if not, you should be able to find one using Google or similar in your area.

Comment: The bypass will run through the ceiling and not through the slab.  Good point regarding the 50% difference in cross section area

Comment: That's a rather important fact that you left out.  There are significant drawbacks to running it through the ceiling, however, especially if you live in an area that freezes.

Comment: It is a common DIY myth that the flow through through a pipe is proportioal to the cross-section, but this is wrong.  The conductance of a cylindrical pipe is proportional to the fourth power of the radius! So a 3/4 inch pipe allows 5x the flow of a 1/2 inch pipe: (3^4)/(2^4)=81/16.